# get_avatar() returns image with margin-bottom

Tags: avatar

Hi completely new to WordPress. I'm trying to add avatars to the page, and following the guide, I'm using get_avatar() function to achieve this. The avatar can be displayed, but I'm not sure why there is always a 10px bottom margin for them. Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just overrule the margin bottom in your CSS? I have never used `get_avatar();`, so I have no idea what class(es) it uses, but just add `.avatar_class_name { margin-bottom: 0; }` and it should work.

If it doesn't, try adding `!important` after the `0`.